# What version of Silverlight is the Pivot control in?

Tags: c#, silverlight, pivotviewer

I'd like to try the pivot control and have VS.NET 2010 installed but do not see it anywhere when I create a silverlight project. Any ideas on where I can find this?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Silverlight Pivot Control from http://www.silverlight.net/learn/pivotviewer/ which directs to http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=9a1bb862-d80c-4145-9320-b279a63bff91